# How to change placeholder color on focus?

Tags: css, input, focus, placeholder, onfocus

How to change the color of placeholder when focus the input field?
I use this CSS code to set the default color, but how to change it **on focus**?

```
::placeholder { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works for me:

```
input:focus::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This should be changed to be the marked answer.

Answer (score 134):

Try this, this should work :

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Firefox < 19 */
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Firefox > 19 */
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

/* Internet Explorer 10 */
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/XDutj/27/

Comment: why there is not :-ms-input-placeholder?

Comment: I don't have IE to test the above, it would be great if someone could test it. AFAIK, IE9 lacks placeholder support : http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: Works like a charm for me.  Didn't test in IE though, obviously.

Comment: No, sadly it does not work in IE 10 because IE uses the pseudo class `:-ms-input-placeholder` instead of a pseudo element `::-ms-placeholder`. Can't test the focus behavior, because IE per default hides the placeholder on focus (and unfortunately I didn't find a way to avoid that). [See this update to your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDutj/27/).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Pranav answer I refined the code with textarea compatibility:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999; }
:-moz-placeholder { color: #999; }

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #ccc; }
:focus:-moz-placeholder { color: #ccc; }​
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete and updated (2021) example:

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<label for="city">City:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="your favorite city">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Enter text' />
```

CSS

```
input[placeholder]:focus { color: red; }
```

Comment: That wasn't necessary, but I suspect it's because, on further inspection, your code would color the actual value of the input on focus, rather than its placeholder text only.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution with JQuery:

```
 $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){

    $(this).focus(function(){
      $(this).addClass('input-focus');
    });

    $(this).blur(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('input-focus');
    });

  });
```

with this css:

```
.input-focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #f00; }    
.input-focus:-moz-placeholder { color: #f00; }
.input-focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #f00; }
```

Comment: JQuery is beautiful, but must die. Everything that has a beginning, has an end, @DavidePalmieri

Comment: WTH are you on @BoltClock. Of course it needs jQuery...If anything it needs moar jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

Use star `*` to select everything

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999; }


*:-moz-placeholder { color: #999; }


*::-moz-placeholder { color: #999; }


*:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #999; }
```

Comment: Note: for some reason, you cannot use commas to apply multiple rules. These have to be declared separately as shown. (though you probably only need ms-input and ::placeholder now)

Answer (score 0):

From Firefox 19:
The :-moz-placeholder pseudo-class that matches form elements with the placeholder attribute has been removed, and the ::-moz-placeholder pseudo-element has been added instead.

```
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color: transparent; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It definitely works -

```
input:focus::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

Code example result -

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text here">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a material design animated placeholder that shrinks on top when input field is focused.

```
<div class="field">
 <input type="text" name="user" required><br>
 <label>Enter Username</label>
 </div>
```

Basically the label field is going to act like a placeholder. We can do this only using css.
Explained here http://www.voidtricks.com/create-material-design-animated-placeholder/