# Is it possible to read the CSS properties applied to input placeholders?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to read the CSS properties applied to input **placeholders** using Javascript or Chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
your question should be a duplicate of [Inspect webkit-input-placeholder with developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852922/inspect-webkit-input-placeholder-with-developer-tools)

---

You must enable the shadow dom on the general tab on your Dev-Tools settings:

[image]

Now you can inspect the placeholder in the shadow dom:

[image]

Ciao
Ralf