# Find placeholder pseudo style in google chrome devtools

Tags: css, input, google-chrome-devtools, placeholder, pseudo-element

I want to test my placeholder style in chrome devtools but can't find it.

I tried to use the "Toggle Element State" but it provides only

1. :hover
2. :active
3. :focus-within
4. :focus
5. :visited

These are my css lines:

```
    .inputs-wrapper input[type="text"]::placeholder ,
    .inputs-wrapper input[type="tel"]::placeholder{

        font-weight:900;
        color:black;

    }
```

html:

```
<div class="inputs-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="שם מלא"/>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="טלפון"/>
    <input type="submit" value="המשך > " />
</div>
```

Comment: `placeholder` is not a state like hover, its the help text in a input, when you click on it the placeholder is removed and you can write on it, so to "see" the style you just need to look to the input !!

Comment: I "stand" on the input element and yet don't see any style properties of its placeholder in the style section and that is what I am looking for.

Comment: oh i got it now sorry, so this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852922/inspect-webkit-input-placeholder-with-developer-tools

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Showing user agent Shadow DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853319/1669860) does the trick.

After enabling this setting, expand the `#shadow-root` section. The placeholder shows up as a `div`.

[image: demo]