# How to inspect ::-webkit-datetime-edit in dev tools

Tags: html, css, input, webkit

I use the `::-webkit-datetime-edit` CSS property in order to control the appearance of a date input field for webkit browsers. To do further debugging, I would like to inspect it in my dev tools.

But when I inspect my element with Chrome dev tools, I can't see anywhere the css properties associated with `::-webkit-datetime-edit`. Nor in the "Styles" panel or the "Computed" panel.

Here is my code:

```html
<input type="date">
```

```css
[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
  background-color: red;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/neiya/pen/jOERJQb

Is it possible to see and edit these properties with Chrome or other browser dev tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question on this post [Inspect webkit-input-placeholder with developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852922/inspect-webkit-input-placeholder-with-developer-tools)

What I need to do is to enable 'Show user agent shadow DOM' in the Settings panel of Chrome Developer Tools. Now the properties are visible.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-millisecond-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-week-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
   color:darkred;
}
```

It may be a solution for your problem, there you have everything that you are able to edit, hope it works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunatly this doesn't help, I can't see these properties neither in the inspector