Bootstrap 5.3 floating labels acting weird in my Google Chrome (Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit))
I recently have noticed a weird behavior with BS 5.3 floating labels. Somehow, the placeholder is also displayed under the label text, which it shouldn't be.
The floating labels on my Google Chrome is displaying like this:

And like this on Firefox or Microsoft Edge:

I searched on Google but didn't find very much information about it, I guess maybe it just happened on my computer?
Does anyone know what happened here and how to fix it?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
PLUS:
My computer is running Windows 11 Pro 23H2,64-bit operating system, x64-based processor;
My Google Chrome (Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit))
BS:
This is what it looks like after I enabled the "Show user agent shadow DOM":


If you switch Chrome or Firefox to light mode, do you see the placeholder behind the label? And can you create a working code snippet with your styles that demonstrates the problem you’re having?

@RichDeBourke, Thanks for the response, I tried to switch Chrome to the light mode or dark mode, the placeholder remains. And you may notice that I took the screenshots from the BS's official documentation site, that is my demo :-).

The bootstrap.min.css file has a style definition .form-floating>.form-control::placeholder{color:transparent} that should be hiding the placeholder text. The style comes from the _floating-labels.scss. In Chrome, you need to configure Developer Tools to show the pseudo-elements. You should then be able to see if color:transparent is listed. I viewed Bootstrap’s page with the latest version of Chrome (123.0.6312.106) and it’s working properly.

@RichDeBourke, Maybe this is the reason why it is acting weird on my computer,  couldn't find this: .form-floating>.form-control::placeholder{color:transparent} on the DevTools page. So how to configure Developer Tools to show the pseudo-elements exactly?

In Developer Tools on Chrome (or Edge), opening Settings and scroll down to Show user agent shadow DOM and enable it. Then you should be able to see the styles that are being applied to the input. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853319/1011984 is old, but has the general information.

@RichDeBourke, Thanks for the instruction, now I have had the 'Show user agent shadow DOM' enabled and saw the #shadow-root content. but it's color:transparent; was overwritten by ::placeholder {color:#828585 !important}, please see the screenshot I just uploaded in my original post.

Your screenshot doesn't show the sources of the CSS styles (usually on the far right would be a link to the source for the style - did you capture only part of your screen?). Whatever the source is for the color:#828585 is why you're seeing the placeholder text and that's not normal. See if you can identify where the style is coming from and eliminate it. If you need more help, post your update in: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257349/bootstrap-5-3-floating-labels.

As @Rich DeBourke keeps helping, I finally found the problem caused by one of the Chrome extensions, called (ProWritingAid for Chrome). Thank you, @Rich Debourke!
