# Styling input placeholder (default and focus state) in Chrome 42

Tags: html, css, input

I'm trying to style a placeholder for input text in Chrome v42
Why does the following code not work in the latest version of Chrome?

Or rather what is the fix?

https://jsfiddle.net/5osszauf/

Note: I'm fully aware there's cross browser CSS. Please ignore.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="fefg3f">

input::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:focus:-moz-placeholder, input:focus::-moz-placeholder, input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
            color: #000;
        }
```

EDIT: I took the code from the stackoverflow post

[How to change placeholder color on focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183421/how-to-change-placeholder-color-on-focus)

If in answer is provided it might be worth updating the answer for this post also?

Comment: the fix is to duplicate the rule, one for each vendor: https://jsfiddle.net/5osszauf/1/

Comment: Oh... is this because browsers invalidate all selectors if one doesn't work?

Comment: That is unfortunate indeed. (oh the pitfalls of web!) thanks for your help. Not sure if this question is worth giving an answer to about invalid selectors... I imagine more devs (who are learning) would fall for this

Comment: @scdr - I didn't see this post however I think this question while covers the same topic does have differences

Comment: it's answered there - a group of selectors containing an invalid selector is invalid.

Comment: Oh right my bad then yeah it's a duplicate

Comment: no worries, it is a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of comma seperated selectors like that and a browser doesn't recognise even one of those selectors it will ignore *all* selectors in that list.

In your example, the `-moz` prefix for Firefox will not be recognised by Chrome.

The fix is to create separate rules for each different prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work:

```
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}
```